# How to write a cleaner (easier) code to the program "Sum-Calculator"?

Tags: python

My task is to write a cleannnn Python program that adds up all the numbers that are entered by the user and prints out the sum of them. My program is finished, but i want to ask if some of you have an better idea to make the code easier and cleaner. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
# class: 4aHEL
# date: 18.09.2020
# author: ---

#empty list to save the numbers of the user
list_sum = []
number_range = int(input("Enter, how many numbers you want to sum up: "))
for i in range(number_range):
    numbers = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
    #add the numbers to list_sum
    list_sum.append(numbers)
#prints out the sum of list_sum 
print("The Sum of the entered numbers is: ",sum(list_sum))
```

Comment: not really, other than possibly handling invalid input I don't think there is very much at all you could do to improve that.  If anything use `cumulative_sum += numbers` instead of append but that is less extendable.

Comment: You do not need a list. Just a single variable.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could use a list comprehension `list_sum = [int(input("Enter a Number: ")) for _ in range(number_range)]`, but that may be less readable, so your code is fine

Comment: Since your code is finished and working, this is a question for CodeRewview  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and not for this site.

Comment: @ForceBru if i do this list comprehension, the programm doesn't work anymore? Can you send your code how you would do it with the list comprehension?

Comment: https://repl.it/@TomerKalish/SiennaFreeScope#main.py

Comment: @python_beginner, what does it mean it doesn't work? This code is supposed to replace the whole `for` loop

Comment: @ForceBru sry my fault. Thank you

Comment: @ForceBru can you explain me how this list comprehension works? is the for loop executed first and then the input part?

Comment: @python_beginner, the loop works like any regular `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily better, but here is a neat 1 liner!

```
print(sum(int(input("Enter: ")) for n in range(int(input("How many? ")))))
```

Comment: Ha. Just posted the same answer.  Upvote.

Comment: you should try [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)